# Context.startForegroundService is not starting a service

Tags: android, android-intent, foreground-service

I am trying to follow the new Android O guidelines to start a foreground service for location updates. When I call `context.startForegroundService(foregroundIntent)` nothing happens in the service class, not even `onCreate()` is called. However, the app continues to run without any errors.

Here is my intent:

```
val foregroundIntent = Intent(context, GeofenceForegroundService::class.java)
```

The context I used to create the Intent is an activity context, not the application context.

Here is the service in the Android Manifest:

```
<application
...
    <service android:name=".services.GeofenceForegroundService"
             android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

Here is onCreate, onStartCommand, and onBind in the service class that is not starting.

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this) //Break point here

    locationRequest.interval = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS
    locationRequest.fastestInterval = 
            FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS
    locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    // setup notification channel if Android O or higher
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val DONT_SET_EXPIRE: Long = -123456
    val expirationTime = intent?.getLongExtra(REQUEST_EXPIRATION_EXTRA, DONT_SET_EXPIRE)
    eventName = intent?.getStringExtra(EVENT_NAME_EXTRA)
    if(expirationTime != null && expirationTime != DONT_SET_EXPIRE) {
        locationRequest.expirationTime = expirationTime
    }

    // If the location permission is off stop the service, it isn't doing anyone any good.
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, makeNotification())
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null)
    } else {
        stopSelf()
    }

    return START_STICKY
}

override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? = null
```

I have tried calling `context.startService(foregroundService)` instead and there does not appear to be any change.
This code is always called when the application is in the foreground, so background limitations should not be the issue.

Any help you can offer would be deeply appreciated, please let me know if there is any other code you need to see in order to find any issues. This is my first time to use a foreground service, so bear with me if I made a really obvious mistake. I have tried to thoroughly read how to do things correctly, but it is possible I missed something that should be straight forward.

Comment: can you please share code of your GeofenceForegroundService.kt

Comment: @Qasim Is this all the code you needed to see from the service? The only code I left out was creating the notification and cleaning up in onDestroy().

Comment: I did find [this somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827498/android-service-does-not-start) but I couldn't find any useful information in it for my case.